# Как передать конструктор из класса от которого не наследоавл

Tags: javascript, ооп, coffeescript

```
class A
  constructor: ->

class B


class c extends B
```

как классу **C** передать конструктор от **A** если он уже наследует от **B** ? желательно пример с функцией **call** или **bind**

Comment: какая цель преследуется?

Comment: разделить логику что бы код был чище и понять лучше работу call и bind